# How to filter data for data visualization in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am required to re-create the visualization but filter the data to keep only the businesses that had terms less than 360 months.[image]

The data I am using is the SBA data from this link:
https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10691898.2018.1434342

```
library('magrittr')
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
sba2 <- sba_data %>% 
  mutate(default_binary = ifelse(MIS_Status=="CHGOFF","Paid in Full","Default"), daysterm = Term*30, xx = as.Date(sba_data$DisbursementDate, format="%Y-%m-%d") + daysterm, recession_binary = ifelse(xx >= "2007-12-01" & xx <="2009-06-30","Active during Recession","Not Active during Recession"), smaller_business_binary = ifelse(NoEmp < 30, "Very Small Biz", "Not Very Small Biz"), business_length = ifelse(Term < 360, "Short Business", "Long Business"))

table(sba2$business_length)

sba_3 <-  sba2 %>%
  group_by(recession_binary, default_binary) %>%
  summarise(frequencies=n()) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(percents = round(frequencies/sum(frequencies),2))

ggplot(data = sba_3 ) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = recession_binary, y = percents, fill = default_binary)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("Default", "Paid in Full"), 
                       values=c(rgb(232/255,74/255,39/255), rgb(19/255,41/255,75/255))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

This is my code so far to recreate the visualization. However, I am unsure how to filter the data to only keep business with a term less than 360 months. I had created the variable business_length when mutating sba2, but am not sure what the next steps are. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
sba_3 <-  sba2 %>%
  filter(Term < 360) %>% 
  group_by(recession_binary, default_binary) %>%
  summarise(frequencies=n()) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(percents = round(frequencies/sum(frequencies),2))
```